# How to load a PyTorchVideo checkpoint for SlowFast Network trained on Charades Dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I would like to build a video classifier model and apply it to videos from the Charades Dataset. I am using PySlowFast model pre-trained on Kinetics-400 dataset. I would like to load a checkpoint with weights as per the Charades Dataset from [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/SlowFast/blob/master/projects/pytorchvideo/README.md).

My current code is as follows :

```
# Device on which to run the model
# Set to cuda to load on GPU
# device = "cpu"
device = "cuda"

# Pick a pretrained model and load the pretrained weights
model_name = "slowfast_r50"
model = torch.hub.load("facebookresearch/pytorchvideo", model=model_name, pretrained=True)

# Set to eval mode and move to desired device

PATH = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab_Execution/SLOWFAST_8x8_R50.pyth'
checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)

pretrained_dict = checkpoint['model_state']
model_dict = model.state_dict()

for key in model_dict:
  model_dict[key] = pretrained_dict["model." + key]
model.load_state_dict(model_dict)
# optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state'])
# epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
# loss = checkpoint['cfg']

model = model.to(device)
model = model.eval()
```

I face the following error when I try to run the above code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4c93f7f28cb0> in <module>()
     18 for key in model_dict:
     19   model_dict[key] = pretrained_dict["model." + key]
---> 20 model.load_state_dict(model_dict)
     21 # optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state'])
     22 # epoch = checkpoint['epoch']

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   1405         if len(error_msgs) > 0:
   1406             raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
-> 1407                                self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   1408         return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)
   1409 

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Net:
    size mismatch for blocks.6.proj.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([174, 2304]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([400, 2304]).
    size mismatch for blocks.6.proj.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([174]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([400]).
```

I understand that the cause could probably be that the Kinetics-400 dataset has 400 labels whereas the Charades dataset has 174 labels. I would like to know how I can load the desired checkpoint to the model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytorchvideo.models.slowfast import create_slowfast

slowfast_model = create_slowfast(model_num_class=157)
slowfast_model.load_state_dict(torch.load("path/SLOWFAST_8x8_R50.pyth", map_location=torch.device('cpu'))['model_state'])
slowfast_model.eval()
```